# Using overflow-y: auto WITHOUT items repositioning

Tags: css

I currently have a div that has a number of equal size inline-block objects inside of it. There are currently four per line. I want to make sure that if there are too many objects for the parent div that a scrollbar will appear. For this I am using `overflow-y: auto`. This is working fine.

The problem is that because the scrollbar takes up extra room that instead of four objects per line, it now only displays three objects per line.

How can I prevent the scrollbar from changing the number of objects per line? I am okay if the scrollbar overlaps the objects a bit.

**Code Snippet:**

In the following code snippet, adding `overflow-y: auto` causes each row to have only 3 objects rather than 4.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 360px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;


}

.block {
  background-color: #55b;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Please see above for a rough example of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for this.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 360px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
   <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```